# How to store Twitter status id_str in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, twitter

I'm scraping popular tweets from twitter search api. For each tweet scraped, I log the status variable "id_str" and check against it prior to every scrape to ensure there are no duplicates added to db. However i ran into some problems:

Firstly, when i formatted the id_str field as an INT it stores the value "2147483647" instead of the status id (every time!!) I really don't know why?

I then i changed it to a VARCHAR field, which was successful when adding the ids, but I find occasionally that dups are added. This happens whether I use an = check or a LIKE check.

So the question is: How can I **reliably store** the unique id_str variable and **reliably check against it** to avoid dups?

I'm using PHP by the way.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because ids are bigger than the maximum value of an integer which is 2147483647. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html

You can use BIGINT or DOUBLE instead.

Comment: THANK YOU - I've changed it to BIGINT and the ids are now being stored correctly. I'll have to wait and see if checking against them for dupes works